# Color bin in hist2d belonging to specific data set

Tags: python, python-3.x, histogram

I have a number of different sets of data `(x,y)` (with different counts/bin) which I plot with the help of `hist2d`. All of the 2D histograms have the same binning. I am looking for a way to plot all of them in one single `hist2d`.

The way this would be done is:

- assign each data set a color (eg: dataset1 = red, dataset2 = blue, dataset3 = green, ...)
- compare the `[i,j]` elements from each datasets and get the maximum out of them:

```
for i in range(len(ybins)-1):
    for j in range(len(xbins)-1):
        hist.T[i,j] = max([h1.T[i,j],h2.T[i,j],...,hn.T[i,j]])
```

- if the maximum belongs to a data set, color that bin with the color corresponding to the data set

I am able to produce separate `hist2d` ([see here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/03BEz.jpg)). As you can see each one is positioned differently.
What I want in the end is the following: [image: overlay]

I am unable to find how to color each bin separately in such a situation, or how to assign a single color to a `hist2d` or `imshow`. I found how to define my own colorbar with discrete values, but then how does one pass only a specific color from the colorbar to the arguments of either `hist2d` or `imshow`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your histogram arrays are `a1`, `a2` and `a3`, for example:

```
from numpy import array, stack

h1 = array([[0, 10], 
            [0, 10]])
h2 = array([[20, 0], 
            [20, 0]])
h3 = array([[0, 0], 
            [30, 30]])
```

First stack them on top of each other:

```
hist = stack([h1, h2, h3])
```

Then use `argmax` to get the index of the array with the maximum value for each item in the stack:

```
hist_index = hist.argmax(axis=0)
```

This gives you the following array:

```
array([[1, 0],
       [2, 2]])
```

Comment: Thank you! Did not know of the `np.stack` functionality :)

Comment: No problem Before pandas there was numpy!